# css style not working in django production enviornment?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-staticfiles

I am beginner in Django. When i hosted a django application with mod_wsgi in Apache2.4. I got a 404 error for my base.css. Any help should be appreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
Alias /cgi-bin /home/vetconnect/public_html/cgi-bin` 
Alias /static/ /home/vetconnect/djangosites/vetconnect/static/ 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_wsgi.c> 
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/vetconnect/djangosites/vetconnect.wsgi 
WSGIDaemonProcess vetconnect processes=7 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP} 
WSGIProcessGroup vetconnect WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Give us more information, how you configure apache server for static files

Comment: <IfModule mod_alias.c>
Alias /cgi-bin /home/vetconnect/public_html/cgi-bin
#Alias /static/ /home/vetconnect/virtualenv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/
Alias /static/ /home/vetconnect/djangosites/vetconnect/static/
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>

`WSGIScriptAlias / /home/vetconnect/djangosites/vetconnect.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess vetconnect processes=7 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup vetconnect
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</IfModule>`

Comment: It is hard to read this. Add it in to your question

Comment: `<IfModule mod_alias.c>
`Alias /cgi-bin /home/vetconnect/public_html/cgi-bin`
`Alias /static/ /home/vetconnect/djangosites/vetconnect/static/`
`</IfModule>`


`<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>`

`WSGIScriptAlias / /home/vetconnect/djangosites/vetconnect.wsgi`
`WSGIDaemonProcess vetconnect processes=7 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}`
`WSGIProcessGroup vetconnect`
`WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`
`</IfModule>`

Comment: Alias /static/ /home/vetconnect/djangosites/vetconnect/static/ I configured the css in this directory. But in browser i got 404 error.

Comment: Are you running ``python manage.py collectstatic`` after having configured Django to tell it where to put the static files by setting ``STATIC_ROOT``?

Answer (score 0):

According official django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) to manage static files you have check this points:

`django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

define `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py`, for example `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Use `{% load static %}` in templates.

you can define a list of directories `STATICFILES_DIRS`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

Finally, you need to set the script alias so that Apache will pass requests for the root domain to the wsgi.py file and server static and media files. [Here is](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04) the link how to do this with full description

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .

    Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject:/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```